# Possible values for ManagementObject.GetMethodParameters method?

Tags: c#, wmi

I only know some of them such as "CreateVirtualDirectory" and "SetDatabaseConnection" etc but where can I get a list of all possible values(method names) for the ManagementObject.GetMethodParameters method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ManagementClass.Methods property returns them, there's a good example in the [MSDN Library topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementclass.methods.aspx) for it.

Have you found the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) utility yet?  Very, very handy to test queries and auto-generate the C# code you need.

Comment: I did not know about the WMICodeCreator... So much time spent coding them manually... You, sir, have my sincere gratitude... Thank you!